# MySQL row format: can I set global or database level default?

Tags: mysql, data-migration

I have periodic stream of incoming MySQL dumps for various experiments and I have not so much SSD space. I need only restore dump and import DB into completely different format based on pretty heavy SQL queries. Tables use InnoDB. I'd like to use compressed row format for all tables when doing restore.

- Ability to use SSD pays off any CPU ovrhead.
- I don't like to modify dumps itself (up to 60G).
- There is no row formats specified in CREATE TABLE instructions inside dumps.

Any way to configure row format as COMPRESSED before restore process? Global or DB level configuration is OK.

Used MySQL version is 5.5.35 (Ubuntu 12.04). Option to upgrade MySQL if needed is not a problem.

Comment: You can take dump in compressed format and restore them as per requirement.

Comment: I can't, dumps are coming from external source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one obvious option to modify dumps with added ROW FORMAT options by something like `sed` replace. It's worst case option as I'd like dumps to be kept untouched for other people around.